# JAVASCRIPT / JQuery How execute onmouveover 1 time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to show a popup when the mouse is over a li element.

My popup got an animation (get visible with fading, comes up, then comes down)

The problem is that my popup's animation seems to be in a endless loops while the mouse is over the li.

I got alot's of li element and I made a process to give them automatics ID, passing them in a 'for' loop.

My code **IMPORTANT EDIT SORRY**

```
echo"<li id='".$li_id_name.$li_id."' onmouseover='showpopup(this)'>";

    echo"<div id='".$li_id_name.$li_id."detail'>SOME TEXT</div>";

echo"</li>";
```

Javascript / jQuery

```
function showpopup(obj) {

 d3.select('#'+$(obj).attr('id')+"detail").transition().duration(100).style('opacity','1').each('end', function() {
        d3.select('#'+$(obj).attr('id')+"detail").transition().duration(100).style('margin-top','-300px').each('end', function() {
            d3.select('#'+$(obj).attr('id')+"detail").transition().duration(500).style('margin-top','-250px');
        });
    });

}
```

**SORRY I DID A MISTAKE IN MY CODE, in fact, the popup is a div inside the li element**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

HTML :

```
<ul>
    <li class="assignenter">LI1</li>
    <li class="assignenter">LI2</li>
    <li class="assignenter">LI3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS :

```
.assignenter{
    display:block;
    padding:20px;
    background:green;
    color:#fff;
}
```

jQuery/JS

```
$("li.assignenter").on( "mouseenter", function() {
  $(this).css({
     "background-color": "red",
      "font-weight": "bolder"
  });
}).on( "mouseleave", function() {
       var styles = {
                      backgroundColor : "green", 
                      fontWeight: ""
                     };

$(this).css( styles );

});
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: sorry but I said : the popup to edit, is inside the li element. look my post again

Answer (score 1):

just use mouseenter instead of mouseover

html
    LI1
    LI2
    LI3
js

```
$('.assignenter').mouseenter(function(){
//What to do..
});
```

Try a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/V3xw8/

Comment: the problem is that I got like 300 li element, so I should write your code for each elements ?

Comment: No, just write it for the `li` in general, `$("li")`

Comment: just give a class to the LI  elements were you need to assign to mouseenter event. Like <li class="useenter"> and than select the element for class ( i've edited the reply to show you )

Comment: then how should I get the li's ID for my animations ? in my code ' '#'+$(obj).attr('id')+"detail" ' represent the ID of the li that mouse went over with the help of 'obj' parameter in my showpopup function

Comment: No, dont just use li. It will apply to every tag in your page. Use descendant selectors to the li you want to select

Comment: @user2372006 -- to get the ID, use an instance of this inside the `mouseenter` function: `var id = this.id;`

Comment: @tymeJV can you write an answer for me with an explicit code because I think I didn't get it.

Comment: @Lwyrn your code seems to work, I ll try it and tell you what it did. by the way how can I know when the mouse is out of the li targeted with your process ?

Comment: @Lwyrn it's dosent works, I ve EDIT my post, I ve forget something important